# subscribe to charger connected event in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

is there a way to subscribe to the event, when charger is connected?

i am developing an application which need to be notified if when the phone charger is connected and when it is disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know when a device enters or leaves a charging state with the currently available APIs.

In fact, there are no APIs relating to power or battery level currently available so there's no work around by polling, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The function `Microsoft.Phone.Info.PowerSource` provides a way to find whether you are connected to charger or not, e.g.

```
    bool chargerConnected()
    {
        return Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.PowerSource == PowerSource.External;
    }
```

and the full documentation via the link helpfully provided by a friendly soul

See [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.powersource%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)